# sort tab delimited file

Tags: python, shell, sorting

I am trying to call unix sort command from python to sort a tab delimited file but I couldnt. When I googled about it I found that adding -t$'\t' to the command works and I worked for me too when I tried to sort from the shell but it doesnt work when I try from the python.

This is what I tried in my script

```
tabdel="$'\t'"
sort_file_cmd="sort -t {1} -k2,2 -k6,6n {0}".format(file_to_be_sorted.name,tabdel)
print sort_file_cmd,shlex.split(sort_file_cmd)
subprocess.call(sort_file_cmd,stdout=sort_bt,shell=True)
```

The `print sort_file_cmd` prints this

```
sort -t $'\t' -k2,2 -k6,6n human_vs_mouse.tab
```

which when run from shell works perfectly but produces sort: multi-character tab ‘$\t’ error when run from python script

How do I overcome this?

Sample data

```
gi|52317161|ref|NM_001004713.1| Homo sapiens olfactory receptor, family 1, subfamily I, member 1 (OR1I1), mRNA  gnl|BL_ORD_ID|10980 gi|58801268|ref|NP_001011737.1| olfactory receptor 1357 [Mus musculus]  3071921 1   307 1.90237e-150    1108.0  
gi|52317161|ref|NM_001004713.1| Homo sapiens olfactory receptor, family 1, subfamily I, member 1 (OR1I1), mRNA  gnl|BL_ORD_ID|460 gi|22129025|ref|NP_667153.1| olfactory receptor 351 [Mus musculus]    302 10  915 2   303 5.70073e-105    806.0  
gi|52317161|ref|NM_001004713.1| Homo sapiens olfactory receptor, family 1, subfamily I, member 1 (OR1I1), mRNA  gnl|BL_ORD_ID|4490 gi|33238878|ref|NP_666817.1| olfactory receptor 24 [Mus musculus]    308 1   921 1   307 9.58658e-105    805.0  
gi|52317161|ref|NM_001004713.1| Homo sapiens olfactory receptor, family 1, subfamily I, member 1 (OR1I1), mRNA  gnl|BL_ORD_ID|458 gi|22129031|ref|NP_667152.1| olfactory receptor 353 [Mus musculus]    302 10  915 2   303 1.01585e-103    798.0  
gi|52317161|ref|NM_001004713.1| Homo sapiens olfactory receptor, family 1, subfamily I, member 1 (OR1I1), mRNA  gnl|BL_ORD_ID|13639 gi|268837230|ref|NP_667200.2| olfactory receptor 1496 [Mus musculus]    3071921 3   309 1.50986e-99 771.0  
gi|52317161|ref|NM_001004713.1| Homo sapiens olfactory receptor, family 1, subfamily I, member 1 (OR1I1), mRNA  gnl|BL_ORD_ID|13345 gi|283837936|ref|NP_666450.2| olfactory receptor 374 [Mus musculus] 310 1   930 1   310 4.18033e-99 768.0  
gi|52317161|ref|NM_001004713.1| Homo sapiens olfactory receptor, family 1, subfamily I, member 1 (OR1I1), mRNA  gnl|BL_ORD_ID|455 gi|22129035|ref|NP_667150.1| olfactory receptor 354 [Mus musculus]    302 13  918 8   309 1.85488e-98 764.0  
gi|52317161|ref|NM_001004713.1| Homo sapiens olfactory receptor, family 1, subfamily I, member 1 (OR1I1), mRNA  gnl|BL_ORD_ID|410 gi|22129071|ref|NP_667122.1| olfactory receptor 1377 [Mus musculus]   305 1   915 1   304 3.06622e-97 755.0  
gi|52317161|ref|NM_001004713.1| Homo sapiens olfactory receptor, family 1, subfamily I, member 1 (OR1I1), mRNA  gnl|BL_ORD_ID|312 gi|53933206|ref|NP_001005569.1| olfactory receptor 366 [Mus musculus] 307 1   921 1   307 2.14345e-96 749.0  
gi|52317161|ref|NM_001004713.1| Homo sapiens olfactory receptor, family 1, subfamily I, member 1 (OR1I1), mRNA  gnl|BL_ORD_ID|4458 gi|58801284|ref|NP_001011748.1| olfactory receptor 867 [Mus musculus]    3091927 1   309 7.36974e-96 748.0
```

Comment: Also, try to split the command using shlex
import shlex
shlex.split(sort_file_cmd)

Comment: Note that `shlex.split`, as used like this, is **useless** because it does *not* modify `sort_file_cmd`. Also note that you *cannot* use `shlex.split` *and* `shell=True`, because `shell=True` wants a single *string*, while `shlex.split` returns a list of strings. See my answer to see how you should use it.

Comment: The blanks in the sample data are all tabs? Because SO is messing up and copy-pasting that characters in a file I cannot see *any* tab.

Answer (score 1):

You can avoid using `shell=True`, simply use a `list` instead of a string as command:

```
>>> subprocess.call(['sort', '-t', '\t', 'testing.txt'])
a       b
c       d
0
```

Instead of building a single stream use a list of strings, each one representing a token in the original command. In your case the complete "command line" would be:

```
subprocess.call(['sort', '-t', '\t', '-k2,2', '-k6,6n', file_to_be_sorted.name])
```

Note that this method is *safer* and you should try to avoid `shell=True` as much as possible. You *must* use `shell=True` only when you want to use some *shell* feature, like built-in commands `if`s, loops, pipes (although these can be build use `subprocess.Popen`...) etc. In all cases where you simply want to execute a command passing some arguments, `shell=True` can be avoided.

You can use `shlex.split` in order to obtain the list of strings from the command string:

```
>>> cmdline = shlex.split("sort -t '\t' -k2,2 -k6,6n")
>>> cmdline
['sort', '-t', '\t', '-k2,2', '-k6,6n']
>>> cmdline.append(file_to_be_sorted.name)   # insert the last argument.
```

Note that in this case you have to surround the `\t` in single-quotes in the original string.

---

If you still want to use `shell=True` then simply do *not* use the `$'\t'` escape:

```
>>> subprocess.call("sort -t '\t' testing.txt", shell=True)
a       b
c       d
0
```

Works fine for me.

Comment: Thank you for your reply Bakuriu but still throws the same error sort: multi-character tab ‘$\\t’

Comment: @user2960593 I've updated my answer with an alternative way to call the subprocess that works. I'm puzzled by the error, because using the raw string ought to make it work. There is probably some kind of conflict between python's and bash's interpretation of the string.

Comment: Doesnt work Bakuriu. No error though but it doesnt sort as I expected. I have included the sample dataset in the question. Please have a look. Could it be because of the data?

Comment: @user2960593: `shell=True` by default uses `/bin/sh` that doesn't understand [ANSI-C Quoting](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#ANSI_002dC-Quoting) so the minimal change is to add parameter `executable='bash'`. But as @Bakuriu's answer demonstrates there are better ways that doesn't require `shell=True`.

Answer (score 0):

The `$' '` quoting syntax is interpreted by the shell.

You need to say:

```
tabdel=r'\t'
```

Comment: That does'nt throw any error but shlex split suggests that it is interpreted as -tt so the output is not sorted.

Comment: @user2960593 `shlex.split` didn't exist in your code.  Could you rather post what you're attempting rather than posting something else?

Comment: My apologies I included split.shlex after Necrolyte2's suggestion. Will update my question. Thanks

Comment: @user2960593 I believe that the suggestion above should work with both your original and modified question.

Comment: `r'\t'` is interpreted as `'t'` by the shell (/bin/sh), you could use `"'\t'"` instead (a literal tab inside single quotes). The original `"$'\t'"` from the question would work with `executable='bash'` parameter.